# AngularJS Smart table does not hold value of input field within table cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

My Smart Table of Angular looks like as below-

```
<table id="smartTbl" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="data.computerList" class="table table-striped">
```

And rows of the table is displayed as

```
<tbody>
<tr id="{{ row.id }}" ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
<td><input type="text" value='{{ row.id }}' ng-readonly="!isEnabled" ng-class="{ disabled: !isEnabled }" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"></td>
<td><input type="text" value='{{ row.computerName }}' ng-readonly="!isEnabled" ng-class="{ disabled: !isEnabled }" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"></td>
</tr>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved" id='EditSave' data-text="Save" ng-hide="hideSave" ng-click="hideEdit = true;hideSave = false;isEnabled = true; editComputer(row, row.id)" ng-init="hideSave = true;isEnabled = false"></button></td>
</tbody>
```

I also allow adding new/edit row in the smart table, but during these operation I can not retreive the value of user input value because I render the page `value='{{ row.id }}' ng-readonly="!isEnabled"`

Any suggestion for how to retreive the value of input field ?

I do not want to use contenteditable & ng-model is not seem to work with input field as I render the data of input  as I have

Comment: ng-model="row.id" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"  solves the problem. Thanks.